# Android app unexpectedly closing on emulator or on cellphone

Tags: android

Whenever I am creating the app, the layout of the app is easily running on the emulator but as soon as I make some changes in the Main_Activity Java file, it always shows me the run-time error that

> Unfortunately, App_name has stopped working.

It is not happening with only one app but with all my apps it is showing the same error.

This is the error which is present on the console whenever the app stops working:

[image: logcat error]

[image: logcat verbose]

[image: graphical layout]

[image: fragmet_xml]

[image: main activity code]

Comment: line 27 of MainActivity. And next time paste directly the logcat.

Comment: Please post your code as well as the logcat file without which its useless to post screen shots

Comment: You need to let us know which is line 27 before we can pinpoint whats the error about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views you're trying to access with `findViewById()` are in `main.xml` layout and not in `activity_main.xml` layout.

One way to solve it is to change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in line 21 of MainActivity class you are getting a nullpointer exception there. if u wish for further help post your code.